# UITabbar loads 2 views on app start instead of just the first one

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have a uitabbar with 4 buttons. The start up screen loads as it should on the applications start. 2 of the buttons views don't load on start (good). 1 is a web view the other is a navigation controller with a table view. The last view does load on application start. It is another navigation controller with a table view.

I know which ones are loading and which are not because i added nslogs to the didload function on all top level controllers.

So the overall issue is that when i start my app, then rotate it, then go into the tabbar item that has already been loaded the header in the tableview which is a webview, never got the memo that it should have rotated, and therefore resized. Once your in the view if you rotate back and forth then it works as it should. Its just the initial time.

Update 1:
The question is how do I stop the 2nd controller that is on another button of the tab bar from loading on app start.

Update 2:
I do all my init stuff in didload but I tried adding the following code, but it never shows up in the log. I am not using IB, this is all done programmatically:

```
    - (void)loadView
    {
        NSLog(@"Loading feedback");
    }
```

Update 3:
I figured out whats causing this. I do have a xib that houses my tabbarcontroller. In that tabbarcontroller i have  a navigation controller, then i have a view controller (I set the class to my feedback class), then i had the navigation item and a table view. When i add the tableview it triggers the controller to load. Simply removing that will stop it form loading early. Then to fix it, i created a xib for the feedback. So I dont like having nibs that server a single purpose, in this case its to get a table view in there and have it be a grouped style. I may try to just manually add the tableview instead of having a tableview controller.

Comment: You have the loading code of those view controllers in *loadView* method?

Comment: I do not understand what you question is? Are you exposing a problem asking for solutions, or is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Its much easier to do in code. The tab bar controller accepts the view controllers in the array and the default tab bar controller is the one which is at the first index of the tab bar controller.

```
      UITabBarController *tabBarController = [UITabBarController alloc] init];
      tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewConoller,secondViewController,nil];
       [self.view addSubview : tabBarController.view];
```

Place all the view related task in viewDidLoad method sometimes loadView gies problem this may be because of your viewController trying to load a new view which calls itself again and again so better to add them to viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller for the tab that loads prematurely probably accesses the `self.view` property before it is needed needed.

If finding he access point is hard add a breakpoint to `loadView`, make a dummy overload only calling `[super loadView]` if needed *(The view is loaded from a NIB)*. The breakpoints stack trace will show you where you force the load to occur.

Comment: I updated the question. But to clarify, i called the loadview in the controller thats loading prematurely, and it didnt seem to be called at all. I also search in that controller for super, self, and view, and didnt see anything thats not default (like `[super viewDidLoad];`)

Comment: @Todd Horst - This seems strange, do you programmatically change the tabs after the `UITabBarController`'s view has been added to the window? Or do you have a subclass that overrides the `loadView`, yet again, that you implemented with a log in it?